# Scala check if None exists in a Map

Tags: scala

I have a Map that has the type:

```
Map[String, Option[SomeType]]
```

I want to know if there are any elements in this Map that contains a None as a value. I don't want to collect the elements, but all I want is to get a boolean true or false!

Not sure if this is correct:

```
  val isNoneExists = myMap.exists {
    case (_, optionalElem) => optionalElem match {
      case Some(elem) => false
      case None => true
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your code already works, but I prefer this: `myMap.exists(!_._2.isDefined)`, also if you're unsure if it's correct you should do some tests.

Comment: I just want to know why this was down voted?

Comment: Why not just see if it works in the scala repl?  It looks like your code is verbose, but works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
scala> val m = Map("foo" -> Some(10), "boo" -> None)

scala> m.values.exists(_ == None)
res21: Boolean = true
```